# Access photoshop's grid from imagemagic

Tags: imagemagick, photoshop, psd

I am currently working with batch image processing and trying to figure out such thing: is it possible to access Photoshop's guidelines on image?
I have a lot of background images with guidelines placed on them and want to combine with other images, using coordinates marked by guidelines. Is it possible at all?

Comment: I would think it depends on the image and a sample image or two may help getting a useful reply. Is the guide line on the image or a different layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't stick to use ImageMagick..

[layervault/psd.rb: Parse Photoshop files in Ruby with ease](https://github.com/layervault/psd.rb)

-> examples/guides.rb may solve

[meltingice/psd.js: A Photoshop PSD file parser for NodeJS and browsers](https://github.com/meltingice/psd.js)

are able to parse psd file.

Comment: Thank you! Ruby utils looks like exactly what I need.